# How to properly change dictionary during iteration?

Tags: python, dictionary

I know there are a lot of similar topics, but my problem is much different.

I have an extremely horrid procedure:

```
def watchForPositionalMouseRequests(self):

    slotToBeErased = None

    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and mouse.get_pressed()[0] == True:
            if self.isItemSelected == False:
                for slot in self.storage:
                    if (self.getInterfaceX(slot[0]),self.getInterfaceY(slot[1])) == (self.cursor.x,self.cursor.y):
                        print self.storage[slot]
                        if isinstance(self.storage[slot][0],Item):
                            self.isItemSelected = True
                            if self.slotHolder is None:
                                self.storage[slot][0].x = self.cursor.x
                                self.storage[slot][0].y = self.cursor.y
                                self.slotHolder = self.storage[slot][0]
                                slotToBeErased = slot # Here I save the slot to be erased when the mouse is still pressed.

        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP and mouse.get_pressed()[0] == False:
            if self.isItemSelected == True:
                for slot in self.storage:
                    if (self.getInterfaceX(slot[0]),self.getInterfaceY(slot[1])) == (self.cursor.x,self.cursor.y):
                        if self.slotHolder is not None:
                            self.isItemSelected = False
                            self.storage[slot][0] = self.slotHolder
                            self.slotHolder = None
                            self.storage[slotToBeErased] = 0 # Here I remove that saved slot only when I release the mouse button.
                            slotToBeErased = None
```

Result:

```
for slot in self.storage:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I've tried to make a deepcopy of self.storage outside the loop and then altering it to avoid the error, but then, the whole application crashes in a way that I've never seen (I get a window runtime-error). I've also tried to increase the recursion limit:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

Comment: Increasing the recursion limit is **not the way to go**. Try reading up on it before you change it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to deepcopy whole dict, you just need to make a copy of keys. Try:

```
for slot in list(self.storage):
```

Comment: if deepcopy is the answer, you're probably asking the wrong question  :)

Comment: Thank you very much! It really solved the problem. I never had to deal with this problem before.